# Example of a function $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $f(x).\int_{-1}^{x}{f(t)}dt.\int_{x}^{1}{f(t)}dt = C \quad \forall x\in (-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

As far as I know, the function $f$, if it exists, should have the shape of a parabola centered at 0 and $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -1^{+}} f(x) = \infty$.

This question comes from probability theory. I want to have some insights into the property of the median (denoted as $Y$) of three independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$. In particular, I'm interested in the random variables $X_i$ producing a uniform distribution $Y$.